# Thrifthive in python: columns are separated by tab but the data may contain tabs

Tags: python, hive

I am using thrifthive library to connect hive server in python. I found that the rows retrieved by thrifthive are simply strings and the columns in each row are separated by tab.

For example

**aa\tbb\tcc**

and what I have to do is to split the row by '\t' and get each column.

But the data is possible to contain tab as well and this creates problems.
For example:

**a\ta\tbb\tcc**

'a\ta' is a single column but it will be split into two by '\t'.

Is there any suggestion on this?

Thanks,

Ryan

**ps. The data in hive is not quoted.**

Comment: Is the data quoted, as in a tab separated field format?  the csv module can handle this as long as there is a quote character.

Comment: Hi fiacre, the data in hive tables is not quoted. Actually what I am doing is  something like exporting hive data to csv files. The first step is to get the data and I'll quote them in the code. But the problem is that I am not able to get the right data when tabs exist.

Comment: THe only other thing I can think of is a regex to count tabs, save the lines that have extra tabs for later processing.  I am unfamiliar with hive, but I have had this problem with exported data and the csv module.  Best of luck.

Comment: It is a normal case for the data to contain \t in my scenario. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you do row = client.fetchOne(), is row indexed?  That would be your answer there.  write to JSON; cols = { "0": row[0] ... } then you can manipulate as you see fit.

Comment: What I am doing is client.fetchN(), but it is similar to fetchOne. fetchOne fetches one row but not one column. The row is a string containing multiple columns and the columns are separated by \t.

Answer (score 0):

The [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) module handles quote characters.

Assuming you are using `"` for a quote character (this is a big assumption and you will need to verify that this is in fact the case):

```
import csv

with open("filename.txt") as csv_file:
    rows = list(csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"'))
```

Comment: Hi Trey, thanks for your reply. The data is not quoted in hive. I just wondering if I am able to change the ThriftHive field separator from \t to others.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. I don't know about that topic, sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your time. :)